# How to parse highlighted part in Image with Json

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am trying this cod but ist showing type mismatch.

```
Option Explicit

Sub nse5()
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim url As String
Dim json As Object
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"

With req
.Open "GET", url, False
.send
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With

Debug.Print json("filtered")("data")(1)(2)("openInterest")

End Sub
```

I have tryed many ways but i am suffring from it that hou to bring specific data to print

Comment: There's no image here?

Comment: `json("filtered")("data")(1)("PE")("openInterest")` or `json("filtered")("data")(1)("CE")("openInterest")`